# how can you tell the requirements for you program?

Tags: system, requirements

I'm a beginner at programming and I was wondering how programmers found out what the system requirements were for their program. I know about RAM and the OS needed to run it, but how about the CPU (or gpu if it is needed for the program.)

Comment: My apps require 8 GB Ram, and an I5 2500k processor. I don't sell applications to poor people who can't afford a real machine. Close-Voting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I calculate minimum system requirements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489696/how-do-i-calculate-minimum-system-requirements)

Comment: There is no easy answer: "Requirements Engineering" is a very broad subject.  Much of the answer is "experience"; much is also "guesswork".  IMHO...

Answer (score 1):

check task manager for the stats and decide with smartness.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest/cheaper way: run your program in a Virtual Machine, then increase and decrease memory and processing to find out minimum requirement for a satisfactory use.