# How can I get the minimum/recommended system requirements for my game?

Tags: unity-game-engine, system, game-center, require

is there a service where I can upload my game in to and they give me the info ?

I want something like

• 2.0 GHz intel core i3 processor
• 1 GB RAM
• 128 MB Video Card with support for Pixel Shader 2.
• The latest version of DirectX
• At least 2 GB of free hard drive space

this type of info for my game

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I calculate minimum system requirements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489696/how-do-i-calculate-minimum-system-requirements)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

### UPDATE

Please, see superlevi12345 answer. Its way better than the old answer.

There are multiple ways to get minimum specs for your game, some easier than others.

Example- Minimum requirements:DX10+ with shader model 4.0 capabilities

For stuff like OS, graphics card, and CPU compatibility, that info can be accessed easily.For example, if you are making a game with Unity, the system requirements can be found here, on Unity's official requirements page.In fact, it even provides in-depth details for platforms, such as iOS, Android, WebGL, and Windows Store Apps.Just look under "For running Unity games" to find the correct info.Other engines should have similar pages too.

Example- Minimum requirements:2.5 GHz Intel Core i3 processor, 2 GB RAM, at least 2 GB of free hard drive space

For more complex requirements(RAM, CPU cores, storage needed, etc), you can test those out on the current system you are creating on.To find RAM and CPU cores, you can use Task Manager( opened with Ctrl+Shift+Esc or Ctrl+Alt+Del, then select Task Manager).Once it's opened, make sure that all apps under Apps, except your game, of course, are closed to get the best answer.Then look at the CPU usage of your game.Let's say you have a 2 core system.If the core usage is really high(I consider high to be 40% or higher), then a good minimum would be 2 cores. If an 8 core system has the usage at 20%, that would make a good recommended spec and so on and so forth.The same can be said for RAM.If a 2 GB RAM system has the memory usage at 40%, then that would be a good minimum spec. And, like before, if an 8 GB RAM system has the RAM usage at 20%, then that would make a good recommended spec.Finding the amount of space your game takes is easy;just add the amount of gigabytes(GB)/megabytes(MB) your game application(.exe or other) takes with the amount the game data takes and you have your answer.I would also record the RAM and CPU usages at different graphics settings, resolutions, and framerates to find the best minimum and recommended requirements.

Now, finally, one thing you could do is test the game on multiple old systems and see how they run the game, and you could use those as your minimum specs.If you don't have access to old PC's, then you could send the game to other people with different hardware, have them test it, and see how it plays out.

And from there, you should have a good minimum/recommended system requirements chart for your game!I should mention that you can also easily add stuff like controller support or online connection requirements, there are some great links to use.If anyone has any questions or comments, I'll be happy to respond!

Comment: If the answer was helpful, mark it as an answer because it certainly will help others! :)

Comment: Looks like you just copy pasted this from http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/711400/how-to-determine-hardware-requirements-for-game-ma.html

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to get minimum specs for your game, some easier than others.

> Example- Minimum requirements:DX10+ with shader model 4.0 capabilities

For stuff like OS, graphics card, and CPU compatibility, that info can be accessed easily.For example, if you are making a game with Unity, the system requirements can be found [here, on Unity's official requirements page.](https://unity3d.com/unity/system-requirements)In fact, it even provides in-depth details for platforms, such as iOS, Android, WebGL, and Windows Store Apps.Just look under "For running Unity games" to find the correct info.Other engines should have similar pages too.

> Example- Minimum requirements:2.5 GHz Intel Core i3 processor, 2 GB RAM, at least 2 GB of free hard drive space

For more complex requirements(RAM, CPU cores, storage needed, etc), you can test those out on the current system you are creating on.To find RAM and CPU cores, you can use Task Manager( opened with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, then select **Task Manager**).Once it's opened, make sure that all apps under **Apps**, except your game, of course, are closed to get the best answer.Then look at the CPU usage of your game.Let's say you have a 2 core system.If the core usage is really high(I consider high to be 40% or higher), then a good minimum would be 2 cores. If an 8 core system has the usage at 20%, that would make a good recommended spec and so on and so forth.The same can be said for RAM.If a 2 GB RAM system has the memory usage at 40%, then that would be a good minimum spec. And, like before, if an 8 GB RAM system has the RAM usage at 20%, then that would make a good recommended spec.Finding the amount of space your game takes is easy;just add the amount of gigabytes(GB)/megabytes(MB) your game application(.exe or other) takes with the amount the game data takes and you have your answer.I would also record the RAM and CPU usages at different graphics settings, resolutions, and framerates to find the best minimum and recommended requirements.

Now, finally, one thing you could do is test the game on multiple old systems and see how they run the game, and you could use those as your minimum specs.If you don't have access to old PC's, then you could send the game to other people with different hardware, have them test it, and see how it plays out.

And from there, you should have a good minimum/recommended system requirements chart for your game!I should mention that you can also easily add stuff like [controller support](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ConventionalGameInput.html) or [online connection requirements](https://help.livestream.com/hc/en-us/articles/212062598-What-Kind-of-Internet-Connection-Do-I-Need-in-Order-to-Stream-), there are some great links to use.If anyone has any questions or comments, I'll be happy to respond!